# Can Outlook 2010 be started without any PST files loaded / quick way to close multiple PSTs in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, pst

Like the title states, is it possible to start Outlook 2010 without any PSTs loaded? Alternatively, is there a quick way to close multiple PST files in Outlook 2010?

I am on a PC that has many large PST files open, and I'd like to close most of them, however, closing each one causes a minimum 5-minute delay, and Outlook freezes until then. Of course, this is not ideal, because closing all of them this way will take more than an hour.

Is there a shortcut?

EDIT:

I found an excellent script that solves this issue at the link below.

For anyone else who finds this and tries to use this script, ensure that you modify the "Mailbox -" portion and replace it with your mailbox name, ie. johndoe@company.com.

Removing the comment tags also increases verbosity when run in the command prompt (lets you know which PSTs are being removed).

URL: http://jbmurphy.com/2009/10/28/detach-psts/

Answer (score 2):

You can use Outlook Web Access or you can create a new Outlook profile (in control panel, Mail) that points to the same Exchange account.  Then use that new Outlook profile (set it up in non-cached mode too) to connect to just the Exchange account if you require the actual Outlook interface to do whatever you are doing.